# Independence of $H(f)=\int_M \alpha \wedge f^* \beta$ on choice of $d\alpha=f^*\beta$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-forms

I came across the following UCLA qual question while studying for my upcoming qual:

> Let $f: M^{4n-1} \to N^{2n}$ be a smooth map between closed connected oriented manifolds of the indicated dimensions and $\beta$ any $2n$-form on $N$ such that $\int_N \beta=1$. Suppose $f^*\beta$ is exact: $f^* \beta = d \alpha$.
>
> **(a)** Show that $H(f) = \int_M \alpha \wedge f^* \beta$ is independent of the choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
>
> **(b)** Show that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, $H(f)=H(g)$.

([http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yingkun/UCLAtopoqual.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eyingkun/UCLAtopoqual.pdf), bottom of page 11)

My computations are showing that  $\alpha \wedge f^*\beta$ is exact, so Stokes' Theorem would imply that $H(f)$ is always zero on a boundaryless manifold such as $M$. This makes part (b) silly, too.  Either way, I haven't been able to make any sense of the hypothesis that $\int_N \beta=1$. Any thoughts?

Comment: This integral is also known as the Hopf invariant, and needs not to be 0. The most well known example for that is the hopf map from $S^3$ to $S^2$. edit: also your integral in fact always will have values in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a $2n-1$-form, so $$d(\alpha\wedge \alpha) = (d\alpha)\wedge \alpha + (-1)^{2n-1}\alpha \wedge d\alpha = 0.$$

Comment: Ah, thank you @DanielFischer! Of course I correctly employed that two lines later, but only after disaster struck. And since I'm still stuck, I'll do some reading about the Hopf invariant -- thanks @mlk.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't think this is correct. $\alpha\wedge d\alpha$ is not $d\alpha\wedge\alpha$, they are actually negative of each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINTS**: 
First argue it doesn't depend on the $\alpha$ with $d\alpha = f^*\beta$. You should end up with needing to know that the wedge product of a closed form and an exact form is exact.

Second, because of the condition that $\int_N \beta = 1$, any other such form $\beta'$ will differ from $\beta$ by an exact form, say $d\eta$. In that case you can give an explicit choice of $\alpha'$ with $f^*\beta' = \alpha'$. Along the way, it should become relevant that when $k>2n$, the only $k$-form on $N$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, @Ted.  Hopefully the updated proof is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Update, Dec '15: I'm moving the full argument (completed using Ted's hints) from the original post to here for aesthetic/legibility reasons.

**Proof for Part (a).** 
Given $\alpha' \in \Omega^{2n-1}(M)$ also satisfying $d\alpha'=f^*\beta$, we first observe that
\begin{align*}
d(\alpha' \wedge \alpha) &= d\alpha' \wedge \alpha +(-1)^{2n-1} \alpha' \wedge d\alpha \\
&= (-1)^{(2n)(2n-1)} \alpha \wedge d\alpha' - \alpha' \wedge d\alpha \\
&= \alpha \wedge f^*\beta - \alpha' \wedge f^*\beta.
\end{align*} 
An application of Stokes' Theorem gives
\begin{equation*}
\int_M \alpha \wedge f^*\beta -\int_M \alpha' \wedge f^*\beta  = \int_M d(\alpha' \wedge \alpha) = \int_{\partial M=\emptyset} \alpha' \wedge \alpha = 0.
\end{equation*}

Now suppose $\beta' \in \Omega^{2n}(N)$ also satisfies $\int_N \beta'=1$. Both $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are closed because they are top-dimensional forms. Furthermore, they represent nontrivial cohomology classes since exact forms integrate to zero on the boundaryless manifold $N$. Thus $[\beta]$ and $[\beta']$ both generate $H^{2n}(N;\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$. Since $\int_N \beta = \int_N \beta'$, we in fact have $[\beta]=[\beta']$, i.e. $\beta-\beta'=d\theta$ for some $(2n-1)$-form $\theta$. This gives
\begin{align*}
\int_M \alpha \wedge f^* \beta - \int_M \alpha \wedge f^*\beta' &= \int_M \alpha \wedge f^* d\theta \\
&= \int_M \big(d\alpha \wedge f^* \theta - d(\alpha \wedge f^*\theta)\big)\\
&= \int_M d\alpha \wedge f^*\theta - \int_{\partial M=\emptyset} \alpha \wedge f^*\theta\\
&= \int_M f^* \beta \wedge f^*\theta -0\\
&= \int_M f^*(\beta \wedge \theta)\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
where the last line follows from the fact that the $(4n-1)$-form $\beta \wedge \theta$ on the $2n$-manifold $N$ is necessarily zero. **QED**

**Proof for Part (b).**
Let $F: M \times [0,1] \to N$ be a homotopy with $F_0=f$ and $F_1=g$.  It suffices to show that

$\qquad$ (i) $F^*\beta$ is exact, i.e. $F^*\beta=d\theta$ for some $\theta \in \Omega^{2n-1}(M\times I)$, and

$\qquad$ (ii)  $\theta \wedge F^*\beta$ is closed,

as this will imply
\begin{equation*}
0 = \int_{M \times [0,1]} d(\theta \wedge F^*\beta) = \int_{M} \theta_1 \wedge F_1^*\beta - \int_M \theta_0 \wedge F^*_0 \beta = H(g)-H(f).
\end{equation*}

To prove (i), first note that $F$ itself is (smoothly) homotopic to the map  $\tilde f: M \times [0,1] \to N$ defined by $\tilde f(x,t)=f(x)$, hence they induce the same homomorphism $H^{2n}(M \times I;\mathbb{R}) \to H^{2n}(N;\mathbb{R})$.  Since $[\tilde f^* \beta]$ maps to  $[f^* \beta]=0$  under the isomorphism  $H^{2n}(M \times I;\mathbb{R}) \to H^{2n}(M;\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $[F^*\beta]=[\tilde f^*\beta]=0$. This implies that $F^*\beta$ is exact, i.e. we can write $F^*\beta= d\theta$ for some $\theta \in \Omega^{2n-1}(M\times I)$.

We demonstrate (ii) directly:
\begin{align*}
d(\theta \wedge F^*\beta)&=d\theta \wedge F^*\beta + (-1)^{2n-1} \theta \wedge d(F^*\beta) \\
&= F^*\beta \wedge F^*\beta - \theta \wedge F^*(d\beta)
\\&=F^*(\beta \wedge \beta)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Thus $H(g)=H(f)$. **QED**

Comment: Funny, there was just another question about a very special $n=1$ case. Like I said there, this trick is clever and used more than once: it's also used in the definition and construction of Godbillon-Vey invariants of foliations (and the argument also shows they're foliated cobordism invariants of foliated $2n-1$-dim'l manifolds).

Comment: @MikeMiller Indeed, that question reminded me of this and motivated its freshening-up! The Godbillon-Vey invariants sounds like very cool stuff. Got a reference?

Comment: A very broad account of characteristic classes of foliations is in Candel-Conlon, "Foliations II" (for which you didn't have to read Foliations I, other than knowing what a foliation is). I haven't read it, though - I learned what little I know from "Geometry of characteristic classes". Foliations seem like a fun thing to learn at some point, but jeez, so do a hundred other things.