# Generalizing the Hopf invariant to arbitrary manifolds

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, differential-forms

I recently ran across a [qual question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822968/independence-of-hf-int-m-alpha-wedge-f-beta-on-choice-of-d-alpha-f)  about a generalization the Hopf invariant to smooth maps $f: M^{4n-1} \to N^{2n}$ between arbitrary closed connected oriented manifolds of the indicated dimensions: Choose an $2n$-form $\beta$ on $N$ such that $\int_N \beta=1$. If $f^*\beta$ is exact, i.e. $f^* \beta = d \alpha$, then we can define
$$H(f) = \int_M \alpha \wedge f^* \beta.$$

In particular, this generalizes Whitehead's integral expression for the Hopf invariant seen [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/33/5/117.full.pdf+html).

Is this a widely-known definition? A quick literature search fell flat, so I would appreciate any pointers. If they are helpful, here are more specific questions: Is it $\mathbb{Z}$-valued? Does it have any useful applications (when $f$ is not a map of spheres)? Is there a corresponding generalization in the language of cohomology? Is it ever actually computed?

**Update:** In fact, I would be happy if anybody has an example of a smooth map of appropriate manifolds $f: M^{4n-1} \to N^{2n}$ and a $2n$-form $\beta$ on $N$ such that $f^*\beta$ is exact (and nontrivial).

Comment: I found some discussion here: http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/claude.pdf.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's great. Plenty to think about in there.