# Hopf Invariant of $f$

Tags: differential-geometry

To set up notation: Let $f:S^3\to S^2$. For a volume form $\omega$ on $S^2$, $f^*\omega$ is a closed two form on $S^3$, which can be written as $d\alpha$ for some 1 form $\alpha$. The number $$\int_{S^3}\alpha\wedge d\alpha$$
is called the *Hopf invariant* of $f$.

My goal is to show that the result is independent of our choice of $\alpha$. Here are my thoughts:
If $\beta$ satisfies $d\beta=f^*\omega$, then we should have $\alpha=\beta+\xi$, where $\xi$ is a closed form on $S^3$. This means that $\alpha\wedge d\alpha=(\beta+\xi)\wedge d\beta=\beta\wedge d\beta +\xi\wedge d\beta$.
So it seems like we must show 
$$
\int_{S^3}\xi\wedge d\beta=0.
$$ 
This is where I am stuck. I feel like I am either way off base, or need to apply Stokes Theorem somehow, but I am not sure how I should proceed.

Comment: $\xi$ is closed so $d(\xi \wedge \beta)=\cdots$

Comment: Oh wow. So $d(\xi\wedge\beta)=d\xi\wedge\beta-\xi\wedge d\beta=-\xi\wedge d\beta$, so I can apply Stokes for the desired result?

Comment: yup, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved in the comments: $d(-\xi \wedge \beta) = \xi \wedge d\beta$, so your form is exact and has integral zero.

I want to point out that this is a reasonably common trick. Here you're using it to get homotopy invariants of maps $S^3 \to S^2$; one other place it's important is in foliations. Given a codimension 1 (co-orientable) foliation $\mathcal F$ on a closed 3-manifold, I can find a 1-form $\omega$ such that $\mathcal F = \text{ker}(\omega)$. $\omega$ is usually not closed; if I remember right, the existence of a closed such $\omega$ is equivalent to the foliation being taut.

Anyway, one then considers $\int \omega \wedge d\omega$. Then this was independent of $\omega$ for basically the same reason as before. This gives a cobordism invariant of codimension 1 foliations on a 3-manifold (whatever that means). One thing that makes this especially interesting is that there are examples of folations for which this invariant (the Gobdillon-Vey invariant) is any specified real number, so foliations are very complicated indeed.

Comment: While we're talking about related tricks, there's a generalization of the above formulation of the Hopf invariant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822968/independence-of-hf-int-m-alpha-wedge-f-beta-on-choice-of-d-alpha-f

Comment: Correction: Actually, the Frobenius theorem states that because  is integrable,  ∧  = 0. It follows that there exists a 1-form  such that  =   ∧ . Now the integral ∫ ∧  turns out to be independent of the choice of , and that integral is the Godbillon-Vey invariant of the foliation on a 3-manifold.

Comment: To say that it is an (oriented) cobordism invariant means that if there is an oriented 4-manifold W with ∂W = M<sub>1</sub> ∪ -M<sub>2</sub> such that W possesses a codimension-1 foliation meeting ∂W transversely, thereby inducing codimension-1 foliations on M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub>, then the Godbillon-Vey invariants of those induced foliations will be equal.